# Scala parallel collections import

Tags: scala, import, error-handling, build, parallel-collections

ERROR: shows error on the word parallel
object parallel is not a member of package collection
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._

:-- Already added this in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, major)) if major <= 12 =>
      Seq()
    case _ =>
      Seq("org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "2.13.10")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you should add
`"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "<version>"` which you did, but the `<version>` here corresponds to the library version, not the scala version, so replace it with `"1.0.4"`.

You should also see an error in your sbt build like `Error downloading org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parallel-collections_2.13:2.13.10`

Comment: yeah I changed the version and it's working now. Thanks